# Issues writing PNM P6

Tags: c, file-io, graphics, io, ppm

I'm writing a program that takes in two duplicate PNM P6 files, puts the memory of the first file into a buffer, creates a yellow diagonal line over that, and writes the result to the second file. When I run it, the output file is corrupted and can't be displayed. I noticed when looking at the output that it's missing the three lines that should be at the top:

```
P6
1786 1344
255
```

I don't know how to programmatically ensure that those lines stay in the code -- I can't figure out why they're even being overwritten in the first place.

When I manually add those lines to the output, the file is no longer corrupted. However, no yellow diagonal line appears. Is this part of the same issue, or is there something else I should look into fixing?

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    unsigned char red, green, blue;
} iPixel;

typedef struct
{
    int x, y;
    iPixel *data;

} Image;

Image *
ReadImage(char *filename)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "rb");
    Image *img = NULL;
    char magicNum[128];
    int  width, height, maxval;

    if (f == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s\n", filename);
        return NULL;
    }

    fscanf(f, "%s\n%d %d\n%d\n", magicNum, &width, &height, &maxval);
/*
    printf("Magic num = %s width = %d, height = %d, maxval = %d\n",
            magicNum, width, height, maxval)
; 
*/
    if (strcmp(magicNum, "P6") != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to read from file %s, because it is not a PNM file of type P6\n", filename);
        return NULL;
    }

    img = (Image *) malloc(sizeof(Image));
    img -> x = width;
    img -> y = height;
    img -> data = (iPixel*) malloc(img -> x * img -> y * sizeof(iPixel));

    fread(img -> data, sizeof(iPixel), width*height, f);

    fclose(f);
    return img;

}

void WriteImage(Image *img, char *filename)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "wb");

    fwrite(img->data, sizeof(iPixel), img-> x * img-> y, f);
    fclose(f);
}

Image *
YellowDiagonal(Image *input)
{

    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < input->x; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j < input->y; j++)
        {
            if (i==j)
            {
                input->data[i].red=255;
                input->data[i].green=255;
                input->data[i].blue=0;
            }
        }
    }

    return input;   
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./3A_c.c <input image file> <output image file>\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

        Image *img;

        img = ReadImage(argv[1]);
        fprintf(stderr, "Read.\n");
        YellowDiagonal(img);
        fprintf(stderr, "Diagonal line.\n");
        WriteImage(img, argv[2]);
        fprintf(stderr, "Write.\n");
}
```

Comment: Opening a file anew for output erases its current contents. So, before writing your data, make sure to write these lines as well. (Preferred over the alternative, which is open for *update*, `fseek` to the correct position, and writing your new data there.)

Comment: So something like this?
`
void WriteImage(Image *img, char *filename)
{
 FILE *f = fopen(filename, "wb");

 fwrite(img->magicNum, 1, sizeof(char), f);
 fwrite(img->x, 1, sizeof(int), f);
 fwrite(img->y, 1, sizeof(int), f);
 fwrite(img->maxval, 1, sizeof(int), f)

 fwrite(img->data, sizeof(iPixel), img-> x * img-> y, f);
 fclose(f);
}
`

Comment: Absolutely not. Try it, and inspect the file! You are writing *binary* where you should use ASCII, per the specifications (and input file).

Comment: Where exactly is the issue with that code? The sizes shouldn't be 1, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful to *write* exactly the same format you are *reading*. The PNM format is [well defined](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html), and you are reading it correctly. However, in the writing routine there were a couple of mistakes:

1. opening a file with `"w"` or `"wb"` truncates it to 0 bytes;
2. best practice is always to check if `fopen` succeeds;
3. reading actual ASCII data can be done with `fscanf`, binary data with `fread`. Similarly, writing ASCII should be done with `fprintf` and only binary data again with `fwrite`.
4. If you want to make sure you write the same data as you read in before, you need to save it somewhere. The `maxval` variable is read, but not saved, and so I cannot write it back. However, it is not a *huge* problem because the rest of your code assumes the image is R8G8B8 anyway, and so `maxval` should always be `255`.

Here is an adjusted `WriteImage` that works.

```
void WriteImage(Image *img, char *filename)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "wb");

    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Unable to open '%s' for writing!\n", filename);
     /* better would be: "return -1" to indicate an error, 0 otherwise */
        return;
    }

    fprintf (f, "P6\n");
    fprintf (f, "%d %d\n", img->x, img->y);
/*  actually you need to write 'maxval' here */
    fprintf (f, "%d\n", 255);

    fwrite(img->data, sizeof(iPixel), img->x * img->y, f);
    fclose(f);
}
```

---

With the above out of the way, you can now see your 'diagonal line' is not correct! I'm not going to fix that (I suppose not being able to see what happened stopped you in your tracks), but here are a few pointers just to guide you:

- no need to return an `Image *` if you are changing data *in situ* anyway
- no need to check *every* single pixel
- check the coordinates of what pixels are changed ...