# Diagonal line in PNM P6 not drawing correctly

Tags: c, ppm

I am currently writing a program for an assignment that requires a single black line to be drawn perfectly solid diagonal (so that all x=y) from the upper-left corner of a standard PNM P6 file. I have had no issues with file I/O.

However, I cannot get the diagonal line to display properly. Instead of the single, solid, white line I need from the corner, I get dotted lines wrapping over the image as shown in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noTYw.png).

Does anyone have any idea as to what is going wrong?

My function is as follows:

```
Image *
DiagonalWhite(Image *img)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < img->x; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j < img->y; j++)
        {
            if (i==j)
            {
                img->data[i*img->y+j].red=255;
                img->data[i*img->y+j].green=255;
                img->data[i*img->y+j].blue=255;
            }
        }   
    }

    return img; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't  give any definition for `Image *img`, so actually this question cannot be answered with confidence; however, I assume you are doing the same class as yesterday's [Issues writing PNM P6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599814/issues-writing-pnm-p6).

You are multiplying in the wrong direction. `img->y` holds the *height* of the image. However, since you need the *span*, you should be using `img->x` -- the *width* -- to go down by `i` pixels (followed by adding `j` pixels to go right).

```
img->data[i*img->x+j].red=255; /* x, not y */
```

Note: Better names for these properties would have been `width` and `height`.

Note: It's easier and quicker to loop only once over the minimum of `width` and `height`, and set pixel[i,j] immediately, rather than testing which one 'has' the same x and y position.